# How to save videos into database using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, model-view-controller, video

My requirement is to save images and videos into the database. I can successfully save the image into the database but I can't save the video in the database. Also, the video can be saved in a folder but the requirement is to save the video into the database. [I am saving the image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCve4.png)

Comment: What have you tried? What error do you get?

Comment: Have you tried this. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Upload-Save-Retrieve-and-Play-Live-Stream-MP4-Video-files-using-Entity-Framework-and-HTML5-Video-Player.aspx

Comment: Is saving the video in the database not a good way?

Comment: @RajanikantHawaldar Yes, I have tried it. But either it doesn't fit in my solution or I can't implement it properly.

Comment: @GuruStron I am getting "Parameter is not valid." error on this "WebImage img = new WebImage(poImgFile.InputStream);" line.

Comment: @UsmanKhan because video is not a webimage =) Why just not simply download bytes and stream them to db?

Comment: @GuruStron Can you please show me in code. Because I am struggling with it for quite some time now.

Comment: `MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();`
`poImgFile.InputStream.CopyTo(target);`
`byte[] data = target.ToArray();`

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks a lot for the code. The video is now getting stored in the database. Thank you.

Comment: Will add as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the `InputStream` as `byte[]`:

```
MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream(); 
poImgFile.InputStream.CopyTo(target); 
byte[] data = target.ToArray();
```

And then store `data` to db.